# ComponentWillMount / componentWillUnmount order after RN 0.43.4

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This question is mainly for contributors of React Native or those who know the underlying library fairly well. There doesn't seem to be a discussion on Github I can follow, so I brought it up here.

In the release notes of [0.43.4](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.43.4), there is a change called "[Switch componentWillMount / componentWillUnmount order](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/5eb3ab3522bd1d46fb4f8471c8207f1e0bc2cc25)". Could someone explain to me what they mean by "*componentWillMount happens before
componentWillUnmount when a child switches*"?

From my understanding of the React lifecycle, `componentWillMount` always happens before `componentWillUnmount`, but the **when a child switches** part is confusing me.